# Writing to a file errors - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write to a certain text file, here is the code I am using to do it

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn);
    if( clickButton != null){
        clickButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText customerBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextBox);
                String customerId = ""; if (customerId != null){customerId = customerBox.getText().toString();}

                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("Registry.txt");
                    String baretext = fis.read(string.getBytes());
                    fis.close();
                    int pos = baretext.indexOf(customerId);
                    baretext.ReplaceAll(pos, "NO", "YES", 1);
                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("Registry.txt",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                    fos.write(baretext);
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

        });
    }
}
```

However I am getting the following errors.

```
 Error:(42, 52) error: cannot find symbol variable string
 Error:(45, 33) error: cannot find symbol method                                                  
 ReplaceAll(int,String,String,int)
 Error:(47, 28) error: no suitable method found for write(String)
 method FileOutputStream.write(int) is not applicable
 (actual argument String cannot be converted to int by method invocation  
 conversion)
 method FileOutputStream.write(byte[],int,int) is not applicable
 (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
 method OutputStream.write(int) is not applicable
 (actual argument String cannot be converted to int by method invocation 
 conversion)
 method OutputStream.write(byte[],int,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
 method OutputStream.write(byte[]) is not applicable
(actual argument String cannot be converted to byte[] by method invocation  
conversion)
```

Would someone be kind enough to correct where I am going wrong :)

Comment: I would suggest to remove this question as it doesn't show any search effort at all

Comment: It seems that you want to use a text file as you would use a database or a SharedPreference. So, why don't you do things the proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... In android you should save the info in a DB or use SharedPreferences.  Its really simple:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString(SP_NAME, etName.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

And if you want to recover the information:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF,getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
String cadName = sp.getString(SP_NAME, "");

if (cadName.length()>0){
Log.d("HELENA","info saved : "+cadName);
}
else
Log.d("HELENA","No info saved.");
```

Comment: That's completely wrong and not what OP was asking. He needs to write a file. It's possible in Android

Answer (score 0):

First error. You are calling for "string" in `String baretext = fis.read(string.getBytes());` when there is no such thing as "string" in your code

Second error. Google `ReplaceAll()` method in Java. The syntax is wrong.

Third error. To write into a file you need to use an array of bytes. Convert your string to byte array and write into file.

And finally. This is a bad question and I think it should be closed because you didn't do any search. All of this is easy to google and don't require pretty much any knowledge to understand.